# Deleting or permanently halting old automator scripts

Tags: macos, automator

How can I delete or stop old automator scripts from starting at startup?

I do not know where they are located and neither do I remember their names. Can I locate them by some sort of extension perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common place to put a workflow is **System Preferences** → **Users & Groups** → **Login Items**. Select the workflow and click the – button to remove it from the list.